# WooCommerce Upsells Same Order as Admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

really hoping someone can help with this as I thought it would be far more simple!

Long story short, I have created a script that populates the upsells of WooCommerce products, all works great using the API and they are there. They show on the product page as expected but in a completely different order to how they were inputted in the admin area and I cannot seem to find a way for the order to follow admin?

```
function filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby( $orderby ) { 
    return 'menu_order';
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 10, 1 );
```

Above is the hook I have found but from the options I have found such as menu order / id / price etc, there is not simply an overide option to ignore the order and just take them as they are in admin!?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. And i have an idea.
I checked all wordpress parameters about Order & Orderby.Link is https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters.

And i use the paramteters name "none",It can make your orderby not based on any sorting rules.In other words, it is sorted according to upsells. here is the code.

```
// ORDER BY
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 10, 1 );

function filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby( $orderby ){
    return "none";
};

// ORDER
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsells_order', 'filter_woocommerce_upsells_order', 10, 1 );

function filter_woocommerce_upsells_order(){
    return 'asc';  // Default is 'desc'; 
};
```

But it is still chaotic, when adding any product to upsells, it is still random. Therefore I also used a plug-in "WooCommerce Drop/Drag For Upsells Cross-Sells", which allows you to drag your products in upsell at will.

If you have any question you can ask me.
Thanks.